# Adding custom name for hazelcast cluster members?

Tags: hazelcast

I'm doing hazelcast monitoring service and I need to add customer name for each cluster member to understand which module is out of cluster.

```
Members [2] {
Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 5ba8735f-af33-486c-9453-cb1d60a71f2c this
Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - 6a0b1f7c-95b8-41a6-9ae2-10142f71a6dc
```

I want constant name of member instead of `"5ba8735f-af33-486c-9453-cb1d60a71f2c"`

Can this be done?

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Note the fiekld `"5ba8735f-af33-486c-9453-cb1d60a71f2c"` is not the name, it's a unique id. If a process leaves and a process rejoins from the same host and port, you need to know if it's the original process or perhaps a different one restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [define member attributes](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#defining-member-attributes) to label your members, however it will not be visible in that log entry. What you can do is use a [membership listener](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-member-events) in addition to defining member attributes and log which member has left the cluster by attribute.

Comment: I'm thinking that HazelcastInstance is object relating to whole cluster, not to particular member. So attributes also relates to cluster, not member. Am i wrong? Thanks

Comment: Each Hazelcast client and Hazelcast member is an HazelcastInstance, members come together and form the cluster. Member attributes are related to that member.